# imitate user activity / prevent automatic afk detection

Tags: android-activity, mouse, user-input, keystrokes

Is there a way to simulate user activity on desktop on Windows? This is the situation: A friend of mine works from his home. His company recently decided to provide their employees with a communication tool which they have to keep running in the background. Apart from its main functionality it also has a very intimidating side effect: It tracks user activity. This means that the programm monitors keystrokes and mouse movements. If a user is idle for say 5 minutes or something, an icon next to his name indicates his idle status to all other users, much similar to instant messengers like skype for example. Now while this may be useful in IM programms, we both find it a bit disturbing in a work related context, for obvious reasons.

Doing some google search only gave me shareware links or cheating tools for MMORPGs. But maybe I searched for the wrong terms. My first guess would have been to have a small process running in the background which imitates keystrokes or mouse movement in regular intervals. But maybe there is another way to deal with this. (Oh, and complaining about lack of privacy to the employer is not an option ;) Also please note that I don't want to promote laziness or question an employer's rights over his employees.)

Any comments and help appreaciated. Thanks!

Comment: I just found a tool called AutoIt. From its description it seems like it executes macros. Does anyone know if the events generated from AutoIt count as "real" user activity to other processes? Unfortunately I don't know how the supervision program actually works.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way to make cursor move in C++.
its something like:

```
 pos.X = 10;
 pos.Y = 10;
```

I dont know if this is the best way, but it works.

If you dont want to program your own program, Im sure there are a lot of programs on the internet. You just need to google :) .